# Error when creating search index in Datastax DSE Graph 6.7

Tags: graph, datastax, dse, dse-graph

I'm able to create a search index in our other environments, but in one environment I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLStream
```

When I create a search index like this:

```
schema.vertexLabel('myvertex').index('search').search().by('myprop').ifNotExists().add()
```

It is Datastax DSE Graph version 6.7.

The build script is identical for all environments.  It looks like Search is installed in that environment, but I'm guessing it's misconfigured somehow?

What could be missing in this environment that the other environments have?

Comment: I would check for duplicate jars, or something like. Plus Java version.  for duplicate jars check look to https://github.com/DataStax-Toolkit/sperf

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Datastax Studio notebooks can get corrupted and need to be deleted and recreated.  Deleting this folder then restarting Datastax Studio will recreate them, but you'll have to recreate your notebooks and connections. (i.e. all your notes in your notebook will be lost, so be sure to copy your notes before you delete this folder).  Then I was able to create Search indices again.  Datastax is looking into fixing this bug, hopefully it will not be a problem in future releases.

```
C:\Users\<myusername>\.datastax_studio\snapshots\studio
```

Also, be sure to enable this on the Datastax server for the user you use to execute commands through the Datastax Studio:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON REMOTE OBJECT DseClientTool TO myaccountname;
```

Also, of course be sure your myaccountname has read/write/execute permissions on the graph.